# How to get segment value on current page to pass in query page on wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

First sorry for my bad english, I do with ajax load more,  when I click  on my category(shop or product) it link to page achive.php

```
 - http://localhost/technology-wordpress/tech_blogs/shop/
 - http://localhost/technology-wordpress/tech_blogs/product/
```

I want get third segment from archive.php page to pass in my query page(fetch_blog.php) (shop, product)to pass in my query

```
'taxonomy' => 'tech_blog_categories',
  'field' => 'slug',
  'terms' => third_segment
  'include_children' => false
```

Here is my code

fetch_blog.php

```
<?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');  
    if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
    $args = array( 
      'post_type'        => 'tech_blog', 
      'posts_per_page'        => 2,
      'paged' => $paged,
      'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'tech_blog_categories',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => third_segment
      'include_children' => false
    )
  )
      );
      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
      $posts =$the_query ->posts;
      if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>
        <?php endwhile;
      } 
  ?>
```

achive.php

```
 <div class="col-md-12" id="results"></div>
      <p class="load_more load-more_tech_blog">
        <a id="load_more_button" class="btn-load">Load More</a>
      </p>  
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?= get_home_url() ?>" id="site_url">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var track_page = 1;
    load_contents(track_page); //load content
    $("#load_more_button").click(function (e) { //user clicks on button
      track_page++; //page number increment everytime user clicks load button
      load_contents(track_page); //load content
    });
    function load_contents(track_page){
      var url = $("#site_url").val();
      $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image
      $.post( url + '/fetch_blog', {'page': track_page}, function(data){ 
        if(data.trim().length == 0){
          $("#load_more_button").text("You have reached end of the record!").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        $("#results").append(data); //append data into #results element
        $("#load_more_button").offset().top}, 800);
        $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received
      });
    }
    </script>
```